# Any idea what's broken here? XCODE

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access, heyzap

Preface: I'm making a an app using a cross platform engine (GameMaker Studio). So I'm not super fluent in objective C.

While testing HeyZap's ad sdk this happened:

[image]

How would I begin to debug this? It happened after I closed a video ad. It doesn't happen every time though, only sometimes.

```
Starific_vGIT`+[HZUtils dateWithoutTimeFromDate:]:
0x3491c4 <+0>:   push   {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
0x3491c6 <+2>:   add    r7, sp, #0xc
0x3491c8 <+4>:   push.w {r8, r11}
0x3491cc <+8>:   sub    sp, #0xc
0x3491ce <+10>:  mov.w  r8, #0x0
0x3491d2 <+14>:  cbz    r2, 0x34924c              ; <+136> at HZUtils.m:265
0x3491d4 <+16>:  movw   r0, #0x4664
0x3491d8 <+20>:  movt   r0, #0x5b
0x3491dc <+24>:  movw   r1, #0xbd6e
0x3491e0 <+28>:  movt   r1, #0x5b
0x3491e4 <+32>:  add    r0, pc
0x3491e6 <+34>:  add    r1, pc
0x3491e8 <+36>:  ldr    r4, [r0]
0x3491ea <+38>:  mov    r0, r2
0x3491ec <+40>:  ldr    r5, [r1]
0x3491ee <+42>:  blx    0x6c18cc                  ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
0x3491f2 <+46>:  mov    r11, r0
0x3491f4 <+48>:  mov    r0, r5
0x3491f6 <+50>:  mov    r1, r4
0x3491f8 <+52>:  blx    0x6c184c                  ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x3491fc <+56>:  mov    r7, r7
0x3491fe <+58>:  blx    0x6c18fc                  ; symbol stub for: objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
0x349202 <+62>:  mov    r5, r0
0x349204 <+64>:  movw   r0, #0x463e
0x349208 <+68>:  movt   r0, #0x5b
0x34920c <+72>:  add    r3, sp, #0x8
0x34920e <+74>:  add    r0, pc
0x349210 <+76>:  movs   r2, #0x10
0x349212 <+78>:  str.w  r8, [sp, #0x8]
0x349216 <+82>:  ldr    r1, [r0]
0x349218 <+84>:  mov    r0, r5
0x34921a <+86>:  stm.w  sp, {r8, r11}
0x34921e <+90>:  blx    0x6c184c                  ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x349222 <+94>:  mov    r6, r0
0x349224 <+96>:  mov    r0, r11
0x349226 <+98>:  blx    0x6c18ac                  ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x34922a <+102>: ldr    r0, [sp, #0x8]
0x34922c <+104>: blx    0x6c18cc                  ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
0x349230 <+108>: mov    r4, r0
0x349232 <+110>: mov    r0, r5
0x349234 <+112>: blx    0x6c18ac                  ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x349238 <+116>: tst.w  r6, #0xff
0x34923c <+120>: beq    0x349246                  ; <+130> at HZUtils.m:265
0x34923e <+122>: mov    r0, r4
0x349240 <+124>: blx    0x6c18cc                  ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
0x349244 <+128>: mov    r8, r0
0x349246 <+130>: mov    r0, r4
0x349248 <+132>: blx    0x6c18ac                  ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x34924c <+136>: mov    r0, r8
0x34924e <+138>: add    sp, #0xc
0x349250 <+140>: pop.w  {r8, r11}
0x349254 <+144>: pop.w  {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
0x349258 <+148>: b.w    0x6bf67c                  ; objc_autoreleaseReturnValue$shim
```

Update:
I've run NSZombieEnabled and this is what I got:
[image]
Note, the crash is in a different place. The place changes each time it seems. It seems to imply a bad pointer to a string object? How would I debug this next?

Comment: Show the code where the crash occurs.

Comment: R7--------Frame pointer. Usually points to the previously saved stack frame and the saved link register.Here you have try to move value of r7 to r7 Register that is not valid so analyses your code first........then do modification if any Require

Comment: This issue might be occurs if you have use local object instead of global.

Comment: Will do. I'll run an xcode analysis and see what comes out. This is all generated code so that complicates things. I'd have to trace it to a problem in the source code written in GameMaker Studio. If it's even a problem with my code.

Comment: It looks like you don't have the exception breakpoint enabled.  You may wish to enable it and try again.  It should stop at the point that caused the crash, instead of deep in the assembly.  Doesn't always help, but always worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, strangely enough the problem turned out to be duplicate file references. The XCode analyzer turned this up, I had XCode solve the problem and voila. No more random crashes.